# Linking an Objective-C framework with multiple targets in the same workspace with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a workspace with multiple framework targets and one application target. All of these targets depend on a common CocoaPod (GoogleMaps in this case). How should I write my `Podfile` so that all these targets can use GoogleMaps without it being duplicated across these targets?

My current `Podfile` is as follows:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FrameworkA' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use    
  # dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FrameworkA
  pod 'GoogleMaps'

end

target 'FrameworkB' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use     
  # dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleMaps'

  # Pods for FrameworkB

end

target 'FrameworkTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use     
  # dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleMaps'

  # Pods for FrameworkTest

end
```

This allows me to use GoogleMaps in all targets but it ends up being duplicated in these targets. I can see errors like these being logged in the console:

```
Class GMSReverseGeocodeResponse is implemented in both /Users/harshad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrameworkTest-ccpoenicmupoxyadfsxniyjogcjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA (0x104b73a30) 
and /Users/harshad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FrameworkTest-ccpoenicmupoxyadfsxniyjogcjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB (0x1043b0a30). 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: Here's the [link to the Github project](https://github.com/WickedLynx/CocoapodFrameworkTest.git)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

def shared_pods
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

target 'FrameworkA' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'FrameworkB' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'FrameworkTest' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. I still get those warnings in the console sadly.